# Simplify boolean expression using other boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra

There are ways of minimising boolean expressions, such as the [Quine-McKluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm)
I was wondering if there is a way to minimise expressions that takes into account also other available expressions.

For example, let's say I want to simplify

(A and B) or (A and C) or (A and D)

Separately I know that this expression is true:

(B and C and D)

With those I can infer that the original expression can be minimised to just

A

Is there a known way to incorporate further information when doing the simplification? I mean a minimisation method, rather than manually doing it.
Also any pointer to something that might resemble even this would be useful.